# How to fprintf some data to a file,and divide them into different columns when opened by excel

Tags: c, printf

I want to **fprintf three number to a text file** and, I try to make it divided into different columns when i open the file with a ***excel***.( now, it's in one column)

[image]

### Below part of my code

```
    FILE *fp;
    FILE *fp1;
    FILE *fp2;

    fp = fopen("exdata1.csv", "w");
    fp1 = fopen("exdata2.csv", "w");
    fp2 = fopen("exdata3.csv", "w");

for (t = 0; t < 1.0; t = t + DELTA_T) {

    method1(t, &xdot1, &ydot1, &zdot1);
    method2(t, &xdot2, &ydot2, &zdot2);
    fprintf(fp, "%lf %lf %lf\n", t, xdot1, xdot2);  
    fprintf(fp1, "%lf %lf %lf\n", t, ydot1, ydot2);
    fprintf(fp2, "%lf %lf %lf\n", t, zdot1, zdot2);

    }
```

Comment: This is more of an Excel question, and the answer is to tell Excel to separate columns on space when ***importing*** the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To tell excel to automatically open file without using import function, use a tab, semicolon or comma spacing between your numbers, and save the file into a .csv file.

**Below an example adding semicolon spacing**

```
for (t = 0; t < 1.0; t = t + DELTA_T) {
        method1(t, &xdot1, &ydot1, &zdot1);
        method2(t, &xdot2, &ydot2, &zdot2);
        fprintf(fp, "%lf;%lf;%lf\n", t, xdot1, xdot2);
        fprintf(fp1, "%lf;%lf;%lf\n", t, ydot1, ydot2);
        fprintf(fp2, "%lf;%lf;%lf\n", t, zdot1, zdot2);
    }
```

Comment: ... or a comma (as in CSV)